# Compact notation to express all permutation of a set

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, notation

I would like to express $$\text{The set of vectors}\,\{\boldsymbol p_1, \boldsymbol p_2, \ldots, \boldsymbol p_{24}\}\,\text{is the permutations of}\,\begin{bmatrix}A&B&C&D\end{bmatrix}$$ $$\text{e.g.:} \boldsymbol p_1=\{A,B,C,D\}, \boldsymbol p_2 = \{A, B, D, C\}, \text{etc.}$$in a more compact manner.  Is there a special notation for this?

Comment: The [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) $S_4$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you could do $S_4$. However, if it's important to you that these are permutations of $A, B, C, D$ specifically and not just any set with 4 elements, then you could also say $\Sigma(\{A, B, C, D\})$. In general, $\Sigma(X)$ refers to all the permutations of the set $X$.

Comment: That is really helpful. Nice and compact. I shall need to read up on this some more.

I need to restrict to permutations of ,,, in order to maintain optimality, so thanks for the additional clarity.

There is just one further query linked to this. If I want to reference a specific permutation, say , is the correct way to define the set of permutations =∑({,,,})?

Comment: I don't think that notation makes sense to me. It seems like somehow you're setting $p_i$, a permutation, equal to $\Sigma$ of something, a group of permutations. Also, what is $i$? How are you indexing all of the permutations? I don't know a canonical way to do so. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Notations) for notating permutations.

Comment: What I am trying to do is reference specific the permutations in a later statement.  So, after I define all of the possible permutations $\sum(\{A,B,C,D\})$, I want to be able to explicitly call out, say, $p_2$ which could be $\{A,B,D,C\}$.  Could I say $\boldsymbol P = \sum(\{A,B,C,D\})$ or $\{\boldsymbol p_1,\ldots,\boldsymbol p_{24}\} = \sum(\{A,B,C,D\})$

Comment: I think the best thing to write there would be $p_2 \in \Sigma(\{A,B,C,D\})$.

Comment: thanks very much!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Thank you, but could you provide a reference to where this $\Sigma(X)$ notation is used please? I have trouble finding an authoritative source.